# Jboss Fuse 7 - Docker on AKS

Tags: fuse, jboss

Does anyone has the link for Redhat Fuse 7 docker image?

I have tried the docker file from https://github.com/jshankarrepo/docker-fuse-7/blob/master/Dockerfile

It works (completely fine) on local windows machine. 
But when we deploy this image on AKS, i can't see any components in Fuse management console.

Has anyone experienced the similar issue?

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: The fact that "it works completely fine" on the local machine would seem to imply that your link is already correct?

Comment: It appears that the image is fine. But, when we deploy this image into AKS, i can't see any tabs in HAWTIO. I am expecting to see the tabs like JMX,OSGI,Runtime..etc.  I have no clue what is stopping this to appear on the hawtio?